# file permssion want to know

Tags: files

I want to know the file permission code

I have run the command and get this code, How can i know which file has which permission

```
ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   4253 Mar 16 10:17 1426481278-xAx-flame.jpg
--wxrw--wt 1 www-data www-data 174613 Mar 16 10:17 1426481278-xAx-flame.mp4
```

Please tell me

```
-rw-r--r-- 
--wxrw--wt
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd` in to the directory which contains your file and run :

```
ll
```

check this link for more details :[permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work)

Hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's see this one `-rw-r--r--`

- First 3 symbols are `user` permissions:

  `-rw` = read and write,
- Next 3 symbols are `group` permissions :

  `-r-` = read only
- Next 3 symbols are `other` permissions :

  `-r-` = read only
- Last symbol is a [sticky bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394067/why-use-sticky-bit), in above case it's unset.

---

Note: `x` stands for execute permission, basically someone is allowed to run a program.